# Angular pass data without navigate

Tags: angular

I am passing some data through rounter.navigate. and then the data is using as parameter for api. But i want to know is it possible to pass data without navigating. Because i have 2 option in the dashboard. Claim status and employes. I need to pass data in both. In claim status, I can navigate because after login I need to show the home screen. But for the Employee tab what can I do?

```
  if(this.loginForm.value.email == 'samad' && this.loginForm.value.password == 'admin'){
    console.log(`found corresponding user.`);
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home', {company_id: '659' , policy: '' }]);
  }
```

this is code of navigating some data to home. But I need to share it to employe component as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways to do it.

1. Parent to Child: Sharing Data via Input
2. Child to Parent: Sharing Data via ViewChild
3. Child to Parent: Sharing Data via Output() and EventEmitter
4. Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service You will find all of these implementations on [this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) beautiful blog post by Jeff Delaney of AngularFirebase.com

I Hope you'll find the answers.

Comment: thanks for answer. can you please reanswer the question you deleted on my other question  i need that code you attached please here is the link of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56091185/ionic-set-marker-on-location-or-based-on-longitude-and-latitude

Comment: Okay sure Umair.